# Button cannot be added to bootstrap 4 Popper content ？

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add a button to the Popover content of the bootstrap in the project, but I don't know why there is no button element in the page.
The version is **v4.3.1**, but it can be omitted in **v3.3.7**. How can I solve this problem? What is the result of v4.3.1 upgrade?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $('[data-toggle="popover-click"]').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: function () { return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html(); }
    });
</script>

<a class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="popover-click" data-img="">Click me</a>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
    <p class="title">
        Do you want to close this message?
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"  id="confirm">
            <i class="far fa-check-circle fa-2x green-text"></i>
            <button class="btn-primary btn-sm btn"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"  id="deny">
            <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x red-text"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question to improve formatting. And include external libraries to run snippet and see what you get.

Well, in my implementation below, I have **wrapped your icons INTO the button**. Then, I have added special btn classes : `btn-success` or `btn-danger` which is quite equivalent to your `green-text` or `red-text` but applied to the button.

I suggest you to build your popover component in the page *(always visible)*, then when format is **as expected**, script its behavior on click.

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     $('[data-toggle="popover-click"]').popover({
            html: true,
            trigger: 'click',
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: function () { return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html(); }
        });
    </script>

    <a class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="popover-click" data-img="">Click me</a>

    <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: block">
        <p class="title">
            Do you want to close this message?
        </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"  id="confirm">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                    <i class="far fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"  id="deny">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                    <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can replace the `display: block` of your id `#popover_content_wrapper` to your initial `display: none` to test your component as you expect.